# Running Elasticsearch server on a mobile device (android / iphone / ios)

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to know if it is possible to run an Elasticsearch server on a mobile device (android / iphone / ios) and if so, how I should go about doing it.

In my case, the reason for doing it is to have an offline database on the device that is easily searchable (with all elasticsearch advanced functions)

Optionally, I would maybe also use elasticsearch's cluster/replication capacities to keep the offline data on the device synced with a server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, maybe (at least on Android, for iPhone the answer is no). Others have discussed it not certain that anyone has succeeded. The Android Dalvik is a JVM, just missing some things that are typically not required for mobile apps. In theory you should be able to try to compile ES and run it on Android. However, you are likely to run into issues with missing libraries and apis that ES requires, so it all depends on how comfortable you are diving in to ES source code to resolve them.

This previous discussion might be of help, you might try to reach out to those on the thread to see if anyone succeeded:

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/ElasticSearch-HTTP-Server-on-Android-td4056423.html

Comment: Hi John, I have a same question. can you give more information about that? I want to make application for google glass. is it possible to use elastic search?

Comment: You mean run ES on Google Glass? Don't think you can come close to doing that.

Comment: Yes! then how else my android based app can search using elastic search? I also may need to update the search indexing

Answer (score 4):

I'm also looking for a fulltext search engine for Offline First mobile apps.

I haven't developped anything yet, but I think the easiest solution can be using the [Clucene](http://clucene.sourceforge.net/) Library (a C++ version of Lucene) as fulltext search engine instead of ElasticSearch (which is based on Lucene - Java).

In fact, we don't need all the features of Elasticsearch for the mobile, such as webserver, restfull api, etc...

You can find some work around on Google:

- https://github.com/asheeshv/CLucene-iOS-Android-Win8
- https://github.com/saturnman/clucene-iOS
- https://github.com/hurongliang/clucene-ios-example

Still looking for a Cordova/Phonegap solution...

Hope it can help.

**Edit:**

I have found this tool that provide Offline First capabilities in Javascript.
It will work with Cordova/Phone Gap and maybe with ReactNative:

http://elasticlunr.com/

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't , at least for now there is no official build that can run in mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use regular ajax calls in your app to connect to elasticsearch? I'm not sure if it would be the best way but that's how I have it going.

Comment: It's definitely a good (best?) way for a normal app, but I'd like to work offline and be self-contained.

Comment: You could use something like Berkeley DB or MongloDB, both are mobile document store and can be synced to the cluster as needed.

Comment: Do you know if CouchBase is any good for what I'm looking for (mostly offline with syncing and good text search capabilities)?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [ElasticSearch4Android](https://github.com/karussell/ElasticSearch4Android) project that seems to try to do just that, but I am not sure it is not dead. 
It has total 6 commits 3 years ago.

Maybe we can put one shoulder there, and help build it.

I will contact the author to see what is the state of the project.