# Elasticsearch client for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, elasticsearch

Does anyone know of an elasticsearch client library for iOS? Would be a bonus if it was written in swift as well.

The elastic search 'clients' section shows multiple libraries for a number of platforms but nothing for iOS, I feel like someone must have done this?

Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I doubt that anyone has - last time I checked there were none and for good reasons. Keep in mind that in order to allow an IOS client (or Android for that matter) to use a client library to connect to Elasticsearch you'd have to open up your cluster for either an http or node access - which would allow anyone to do anything to your cluster.

Maybe you could proxy it to prevent deletions and insertions but even so it would open up your cluster's data and open you up to DoS attacks.

Generally a better idea is to create your own REST API that incorporates some type of authentication and authorization and does not open up your cluster to the world.

If you still feel strongly about moving forward you can always just hit the http interface of the REST API for ES. Or take a look at this project someone was working on a few years ago at least to give you a head start:

https://github.com/tallpsmith/ElasticSearchIOSHead

Some recent discussions on this topic:

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Objective-C-client-for-ElasticSearch-iphone-ipad-etc-td3911216.html

[Running Elasticsearch server on a mobile device (android / iphone / ios)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218159/running-elasticsearch-server-on-a-mobile-device-android-iphone-ios)

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply. I should have been more explicit in my question. What I'm looking for is a library for constructing the ES queries, not actually executing them against the ES cluster. We will pass the constructed json through a security layer onto a micro-service which will interact with our ES instance.

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing out there that I am aware of, other than the one github project from a few years ago that I linked to in my answer.  The challenge with the architectural pattern you are pursuing is that every time you want to change your query construction logic you will need to build and deploy thru the app store - IMHO better to send the raw search parameters to your microservice and construct the the query there.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for. [ElasticSwift](https://github.com/pksprojects/ElasticSwift). Seems to be in active development but haven't looked deep into how far they've gone.

This is another iOS Swift client that was made back in 2018: [Appbase-Swift](https://github.com/appbaseio/appbase-swift). It's a lightweight ElasticSearch/appbase.io client. Doesn't seem like it's been updated in awhile though.

Answer (score -1):

We tried a lot for elastic and finally concluded that it on most of the challenging side. another thing is a bit bulky to use on mobile, as per my understanding no room for the optimization. We can only use HTTP Web Service call for the same service. Also, the flavor of the offline search can not be implemented in the mobile elastic till date...