# Performance issues about fetching results via calling firebase cloud functions for autocomplete in Swift

Tags: swift, performance, rest, firebase, elasticsearch

In my ElasticSearch server, I have an indice called `tags` like this:

```
tags
    - tag_id_1
        - name: "Stack Overflow"
        - popularity: 100
    - tag_id_2
        - name: "Stack Exchange"
        - popularity: 80
    - tag_id_3
        - name: "Something else"
        - popularity: 20
```

Where each tag has a `name` and `popularity`. When users search with query "Stack", for example, in the backend, an ElasticSearch is performed and all tags containing the word "Stack" are returned and sorted by their popularity, in decreasing order, then displayed in a `UITableView`.

However, I learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043765/elasticsearch-client-for-ios) that I shouldn't open my ElasticSearch cluster to everybody, instead, I should create my own REST API that fetches results from my cluster and give the result back. So I did. Look at the picture below, it shows exactly what all this is doing:

[image]

However, Firebase Cloud Function seems to be very slow. I wish to show the result almost immediately after the search text has changed. But usually the result comes back after 3 - 4 seconds. A good example would be GoogleMaps: When I use GoogleMaps and search for an address, the autocomplete suggestions get returned and displayed very fast as if all the addresses in the world are stored on my phone.

**How do I make this happen? Should I not use Cloud Functions for this feature?**

**---------------------------UPDATE 1--------------------------------**

Look at the GIF below, I'm fetching the search results by calling Firebase Cloud Function, notice that after I entered "S", then several seconds later, the results come in:

[image]

the code for Cloud Function is:

```
exports.searchTags = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const { query } = req.query;

    const ESConfig = {
        uri: `https://<some_url>/tags/tag/_search`,
        method: 'GET',
        json: true,
        auth: // My ES authentication
        body: {
            query: {
                regexp: { name: `.*${query.toLowerCase()}.*` }
                // Use regex to match any tags that contains "query"
            },
            sort: [
                {
                    popularity: { order: 'desc' }
                    // Sort by popularity
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    // "request" is a node module called "request-promise"
    request(ESConfig).then((results) => {
        let tags = [];
        results.hits.hits.forEach((hit) => tags.push(hit["_source"].name))
        return res.status(200).send(tags)
    }).catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error))
})
```

**However**, when I perform the same ElasticSearch by connecting the device to my ElasticSearch cluster directly, instead of calling cloud function, the search results come in within half a second, which is what I want:

[image]

**---------------------------UPDATE 2--------------------------------**

I did what @DougStevenson suggested:

1. At the beginning of my app's `startToSearch` method, I created a time stamp `startTime = new Date()`
2. At the beginning of my Cloud Function, I created a time stamp `requestReceivedTime = new Date()`
3. In my Cloud Function, after the ElasticSearch is completed and before returning the result, I created a time stamp `elasticSearchCompleteTime = new Date()`
4. In my app, when receive the result, I created another time stamp `getResultTime = new Date()`

After doing a little simple math, I discovered that

1. Connecting to Cloud Function (haven't executed yet) takes about 2.5 seconds, but sometimes only 0.5 second, it varies: `requestReceivedTime - startTime`
2. Elastic Search takes only 0.1 - 0.2 seconds: `elasticSearchCompleteTime - requestReceivedTime`
3. Total time taken is usually 3 seconds: `getResultTime - startTime`

Therefore, I found that every step else takes very little time, except for "connecting to Cloud Functions", which takes 2.5 seconds. I don't know why this would happen though, I have very fast Internet.

Comment: Do you have specific timings and benchmarks to show?  If not, I can only assume that time could be lost in many hops between the client and Elastic Search.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, I have updated my question, could you please take a look?

Comment: I don't doubt that the user would perceive things as very slow, but you're not giving any specific benchmarks that show *where exactly* you've proven that there is slowness.  The client's internet connection could be slow. Elastic Search could be slow. The connection between Cloud Functions and Elastic Search could be slow. Cloud Functions could be slow.  They all could be slow together. We just don't know.  You'll have to benchmark the individual components to track down what exactly is slow, and only then can you optimize.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson, I updated the question again, I hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Sounds like you're just running into the cold start problem for the first access of a Cloud Function, which is not something you can improve.